# Grunt-Replace for Compiled Email Templates

Tags: php, regex, gruntjs

I'm using Lee Munroe's [grunt-email-workflow](https://github.com/leemunroe/grunt-email-workflow) to build out a set of email templates for a PHP framework that doesn't have a template engine, ie: it uses raw php variables `<?= $firstname; ?>` etc, in the templates.

All was going well until I tried to implement those variables in the email sources, then I found out that `assemble` chokes and throws errors anytime it comes across a variable.

The `gruntfile` for this project already includes `grunt-replace` so my thought was to do a replace on text that won't be parsed by `handlebars` like `## item ##` and turn it into braces `{{ item }}`, then I can use Twig on the PHP app to parse the PHP.

My problem is I can't resolve the `replacement` part of the `grunt-replace`.

I found [this article](https://smyl.es/using-grunt-with-grunt-replace-to-replace-handlebarsmustache-with-package-json-variables/) which does something similar to what I want but that replacement function won't work for this.

So far I have this:

```
replace: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            usePrefix: false,
            patterns: [
                {
                    match: /\##[^##]*\##/g,
                    replacement: ???????
                }
            ]
        },
        files: {
          expand: true,
          flatten: true,
          src: ['<%= paths.dist %>/**/*.html'],
          dest: '<%= paths.dist %>/'
        },
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After some additional attempts I have this:

```
replace: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            usePrefix: false,
            patterns: [
                {
                  match: /\##[^##]*\##/g,
                  replacement: '{{ $1 }}'
                }
            ]
        },
        files: [
            {
              expand: true,
              flatten: true,
              src: ['<%= paths.dist %>/front/*.html'],
              dest: '<%= paths.dist %>/front/'
            },
            {
              expand: true,
              flatten: true,
              src: ['<%= paths.dist %>/back/*.html'],
              dest: '<%= paths.dist %>/back/'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In my compiled templates `## firstname ##` is now replaced with `{{ $1 }}`

How do I get the value of the content within the matched tags for the replacement?

Comment: Try `match: /##([^#]*(?:#(?!#)[^#]*)*)##/g` or `/##([\s\S]*?)##/g`.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a capturing group (round brackets, parentheses) around the pattern you need to capture the value of, and a construct that will match any number of any symbols from ## to the closest ##:

Either use a lazy construct:

```
match: /##([^#]*(?:#(?!#)[^#]*)*)##/g
```

Or use an unrolled version of it:

```
match: /##([\s\S]*?)##/g
```